# Volume Icon disappears in win 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, icons

The Volume Icon occasionally disappears in win 7. It does not seem to be caused by any one operation.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When it disappears do sounds keep playing? Anything in your Event Logs regarding you sound device or the Windows Audio service having problems?

Comment: Is this a new problem? What are the notification settings for Volume?

Comment: Thanks both. I searched the net and found directions to go to the manufacturers website and make sure the drivers were up to date. I did this and ended up installing about 6 drivers in all on their recommendation. I now have the icon again - I will see how long it will stay. Regards,

Comment: Thank you for coming back with solution. For benefit of others, please convert your comment into an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the net and found directions to go to the manufacturers website and make sure the drivers were up to date. I did this and ended up installing about 6 drivers in all on their recommendation. I now have the icon again - I will see how long it will stay. Regards,